# Symfony framework error

Tags: frameworks, symfony1

I downloaded an existing symfony framework application, and tried to install it in my local machine. I'm getting an error, it's pasted below.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 
'The application "" does not exist.' in /usr/share/php/symfony/config/sfProjectConfiguration.class.php:609 
Stack trace: 
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/deal51/trunk/web/index.php(56): sfProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('', 'prod', true)
#1 {main} thrown in /usr/share/php/symfony/config/sfProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 609
```

Could you please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

You should first make an application. If you for example have an main application called frontend your index.php should read:

sfProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', true);

If you have no applciation you can generate one:
./symfony generate:app frontend

Comment: +1. And don't forget to check your configuration, see http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/02-Prerequisites